# How to remove gems from Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to remove a gem from my project so I went into the gem file and commented it out.

```
...
gem some_gem
# gem 'gem_I_dont_want'
gem another_gem
....
```

Then I run

```
bundle
```

To check that the gem is gone, I type

```
bundle show
```

But I still see the gem there

```
...
* some_gem
* gem_I_dont_want
* another_gem
```

Am I not understanding how bundle works?  Is there something more I'm suppose to do?

Comment: Is gem_I_dont_want a dependency of another gem that you do want? Is the gem mentioned in your Gemfile.lock file?

Comment: I don't believe gem_I_dont_want is a dependency of another gem. Yes, "gem_I_dont_want" is in the Gemfile.lock.

Comment: If the gem's entry appears indented after another gem in Gemfile.lock then this would show a dependency. Otherwise I'm stumped -- to check, I removed a gem with no dependencies and it was removed from bundle show's output.

Comment: Oops, you're right Ian.  It is a dependency.  Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: Good stuff, glad to have helped! I've made an answer from the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gem could be a dependency of another gem which would explain its presence in `bundle show`.

If the gem appears indented beneath another gem within the Gemfile.lock file then it would indicate that it's included still because it's a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

There is still this gem until you clean your Bundle using:

```
bundle clean
```

But you don't need to fear. It mean that this package is installed but it wouldn't load into your app until you let it.