# uninitialized constant VideoObserver error after removing observer from application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have installed the rails-observer gem. My current rails -v is 5.2. However i find it not useful and choose to delete it. But the NameError uninitialised constant videoobserver occurs on my page but disappear after refreshing for a few times. The error message highlighted the line:

```
CoreExt::ActiveSupport.without_bootsnap_cache { super }
```

My application.rb does not have the configuration for observer anymore and i dont have a videoobserver model anymore. Deleted the gem from gem file too. What could possibly cause the problem?

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Niibori
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.
  end
end
```

```
   # If the constant was actually loaded, something else went wrong?
     raise(e) if from_mod.const_defined?(const_name)
     CoreExt::ActiveSupport.without_bootsnap_cache { super } <-- the errorline
   end

   # Signature has changed a few times over the years; easiest to not
```

Answer (score 0):

After you removed it from the gemfile you should run bundle again. You can also try what some others have like `gem uninstall rails-observer`

[How to remove gem from Ruby on Rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250362/how-to-remove-gem-from-ruby-on-rails-application)

As an answer in this:
[How to remove gems from Rails project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157375/how-to-remove-gems-from-rails-project)

Perhaps you want to run `bundle clean`.

Comment: did that too, it says gem rails-observer not installed:(

Comment: Oh dang sorry, I am at a loss then :(

Comment: My best guess is somehow it is not the gem but you still have the code for the constant videoobserver somewhere in your code and when it runs into it , you get your error.

Comment: Next time you get the error post the full stack trace is the best bet to track it down